# Edit an information after clicking on an icon

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a project since last week and I got to a part where I am supposed to provide an editable content for the user to edit some informations.

This is what I am trying to improve.

```css
.setting {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 7px 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d6d1af;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.setting span {
  float: left; 
  width: 250px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.setting img { 
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section id="settings" class="hidden">
        <p>Edit your user settings:</p>
        
        <p class="setting"><span>Name </span> Prince Lionel N'zi <img src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
        
        <p class="setting"><span>E-mail </span> lolno@gmail.com <img src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
        
        <p class="setting"><span>Mobile Number </span> +233267689067 <img src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
        
        <p class="setting"><span>Address </span> Weekly <img src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
        
        <p class="setting"><span>Company Name </span> None <img src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
  
        <p class="setting"><span>Telephone </span> +233267689067 <img src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
      </section>
```

Please Let me know how I can make those two things. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made an attempt at creating a script to do this?

Comment: To be honnest, my knowledges in JS are very limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS feature `contenteditable` can easily solve your problem as you are not good in `javascript`.

You can get more details here: [contenteditable article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)

hope, It is helping.

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking for.

Comment: I will share a javascript article, when it will be available

Answer (score 1):

In case you were still curious after the previous answer, I messed around with your code a bit. I used jquery, because that's what I am used to, but you certainly don't have to. I also changed your html a little bit, so just be aware of that.

This is what I came up with:

```js
 
 
   $(function() {
    $(".edit").click(function() {
   var input = $(this).parent().html();
     var preEntry = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("</span> ") + 8)
     var entry = input.substring(input.indexOf("</span> ") + 8, input.indexOf("<img"));
     var postEntry = input.substring(input.indexOf("<img"));

        var title = $(this).parent().attr('id');

     $(this).parent().html(preEntry + '<input name="'+ title + '" type="text" value="'+ entry +'">' + postEntry);

        $("#" + title + "-check").attr("style", "display : block;");
  });
});
```

```css
setting {
      display: block;
      font-weight: normal;
      padding: 7px 3px;
      border-top: 1px solid #d6d1af;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .setting span {
      float: left; 
      width: 250px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .setting img { 
      cursor: pointer;
      float: right;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }

    .check {
     display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="settings" class="hidden">
            <p>Edit your user settings:</p>
            
            <p id="name" class="setting"><span>Name </span> Prince Lionel N'zi <img class="edit"  id="name-edit" src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img class="check" id="name-check" src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
            
            <p id="email" class="setting"><span>E-mail </span> lolno@gmail.com <img id="email-edit" class="edit" src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img id="email-check" class="check" src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
            
            <p id="mobile" class="setting"><span>Mobile Number </span> +233267689067 <img id="mobile-edit" class="edit" src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img id="mobile-check" class="check" src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
            
            <p id="address" class="setting"><span>Address </span> Weekly <img id="address-edit" class="edit" src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img id="address-check" class="check" src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
            
            <p id="comp-name" class="setting"><span>Company Name </span> None <img id="comp-name-edit" class="edit" src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img id="comp-name-check" class="check" src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
      
            <p id="tel" class="setting"><span>Telephone </span> +233267689067 <img id="tel-edit" class="edit" src="https://sharpsnippets.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/editsvg.png" alt="*Edit*"> <img id="tel-check" class="check" src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/successful-check-icon-73477.png" alt="*Edit*"></p>
          </section>
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I was looking for. But I am facing a problem with your code.

Comment: Everything works fine but when I am trying to edit the name, the words after  the apostrophe do not appear. Any idea about how I can fix it ?

Comment: Oh yah, that is a problem with my implementation. I've included a function to escape the html entities, which should take care of the issue. I also swapped the order of apostrophes and quotation marks and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Looking fine now. Do i need to use the function `htmlentities()`, if I am working with PHP ?

Comment: Nope, I just edited it out. However, it is generally good practice to sanitize any data being between the client and server, for security purposes.

Comment: Thanks for providing your help

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask any more questions you have.

Comment: How can I contact you in case I need your help ?

Comment: Just comment here if you have questions about this code or extensions of it.